# Admin & Cart not working correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, cart

My website is www.caviarofswitzerlandshop.com Magento 1.9.2.1

The problem is in administration panel, whatever change I make, it takes a long time to save the changes and sometimes it doesn't save the changes.

In frontend, the cart isn't working because when I add products they don't get added appart from the first one, and when I try to remove/edit product quantity nothing happens.

I have no cache extension installed, I refreshed and flashed all caches, I have replaced .htaccess with new one, I have reindexed the whole website.

Server is shared server. The Website is very small only 4 products on it and around 1000 visitors a month.

It says server load 0.07 (32 cpus)
Memory used 24.05%

**3rd part modules**

- fs_DisableCompare 0.0.1 (beta)
- Aoe_Scheduler 0.3.2 (stable),
- Raveinfosys_Deleteorder   1.0.8 (stable),
- Apptrian_Image_Optimizer  1.2.1 (stable),
- Apptrian_Minify_HTML_CSS_JS

Update: All 3rd party extensions are now removed but problem is still there.

Comment: Sounds like you need a bigger server. Can you update your question text with the specs of the server? (CPU and RAM, etc)

Comment: I have added what I could find, however I don't think I need a bigger server. I barely get any traffic and the pageviews are very few.

Comment: hm okay, that's pretty strange. Can you turn on the slow query log with a low threshold? Or if you have new relic maybe check that. Might be a module that performs poorly. Also, perhaps update with a list of 3rd party  modules you're using

Comment: These are the extensions added:
Wfs_DisableCompare 0.0.1 (beta), Aoe_Scheduler 0.3.2 (stable), Raveinfosys_Deleteorder 1.0.8 (stable), Apptrian_Image_Optimizer 1.2.1 (stable), Apptrian_Minify_HTML_CSS_JS.

I have disabled all of them with no change. I don't think its performance issue but it looks like one.

Comment: Hm, none stand out to me. I would suggest using a profiler like Aoe_Profiler, blackfire or New Relic to find what takes so long

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if any **third party module is there that override Mage_Checkout module**.

app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

This controller file do things like add product to cart or update

Comment: I removed all third party extensions and the problem is still there.